# Adding Multiple Components In Seperate Classes to JFrame In Another Class

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, components

I have ran into a problem. The problem lies with adding multiple components to a JFrame, all within separate classes. I have to add the two components DrawBoard and QuestionBox into the JPanel 'panel' in the Board class. The DrawBoard and QuestionBox will both perform different functions.

The DrawBoard component should be 600x600 pixels, while the QuestionBox component should be 600x120 pixels. The DrawBoard is at the bottom and the QuestionBox sits at the top. I am not sure as to what layout to use.

When run I get this result.

[image: The result when ran]

Game class

```
package snake;

//This class is used to run the game.
public class Game {

    /**
     * @author HyperBlue
     */

    public static Board board;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Creates an object board from the Board() construct
    board = new Board();

    }


}
```

Board Class

```
public class Board implements ActionListener {

    public DrawBoard drawBoard;
    public QuestionBox questionBox;

    public Timer ticker = new Timer(20, this);

    public Board() {

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
        frame.pack();
        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
        JPanel container = new JPanel();

        questionBox = new QuestionBox();
        drawBoard = new DrawBoard();

        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        container.add(questionBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(drawBoard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600+insets.left + insets.right, 720 +insets.bottom + insets.top));

        frame.add(container);

        //Sets the frame in middle of screen
        frame.setLocation((dim.width / 2) - (frame.getWidth() / 2), (dim.height / 2) - (frame.getHeight() / 2));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

DrawBoard Class

```
package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//Warnings will not be thrown (are suppressed).
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class DrawBoard extends JPanel{

    public static Color yellow = new Color(13816442);

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(yellow);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    }
}
```

QuestionBox Class

```
package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class QuestionBox extends JPanel{

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 120);
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI: You can use `setBackground` to change the background color of components, instead of having to overriding `paintComponent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each component should be responsible for managing it's own size, you should start by overriding `getPreferredSize` of the panels and returning the size you would like to use.

You should also not rely on magic numbers, but instead should use actual physical values, for example, instead of

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 120);
```

You should use...

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }

    public Test1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new DrawBoard());
            add(new QuestionBox(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

    public static class DrawBoard extends JPanel {

        public static Color yellow = new Color(13816442);

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(yellow);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
        }
    }

    public static class QuestionBox extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 120);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 120);
        }

    }
}
```

You should also know that `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` is not the most reliable method for determining the visible screen area, as it does not take into account various OS elements, like the task bar or dock, which can take up screen space.